# ¿Organizar Modelos Laravel En Carpetas?

Tags: php, laravel

asi como puedo organizar mis migraciones y Controladores en laravel por carpetas, puedo hacer lo mismo con los Modelos?

Comment: Si, tenes que seguir, al igual que [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/contributions#coding-style), los standards prs-2  y [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)